# Having trouble running the jos kernel of mit 6.828

Tags: gcc, operating-system, qemu

OS: ubuntu-17.10-amd64
[image]

It seems that the building process succeed but the kernel failed running in qemu.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to investigate the problem here, but failed. Somehow I managed to fix it by building a i386-elf-gcc toolchain by myself and use that instead of gcc-multilib. Then it works properly.

I am using macOS, so I used this:

```
$ brew tap nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain
$ brew install i386-elf-gcc --verbose
```

Then I replaced all "i386-jos-elf" with "i386-elf" in GNUmakefile.